# What is a good dead simple project management tool?

Tags: pm-software

I'm looking for a no frills, cheap/free online project management tool. Recommendations?

Comment: Hi Leonard, welcome to PMSE. [Recommendations and shopping questions are off-topic.](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/351/we-will-be-closing-all-tool-recommendations-within-2-weeks) Also, see previously asked questions with the [tag:pm-software] tag, as well as the [pm-software tag wiki](http://pm.stackexchange.com/tags/pm-software/info), which has the beginnings of a compiled list of tools. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An Excell spreadsheet stored on a common repository. I ran a million unit a quarter business (about 5-6 million quarterly profit) with a single Excell file that had four worksheets in it. 90% of the data  for all projects was in that file. It was simple, everyone understood it and I sent it out and posted it weekly.

If you're looking for collaborative workspace, [Basecamp](http://basecamp.com/) is a good tool and I think they have a free option.

A really simple Agile/ Kanban task board system, that can be shared, is [Trello](https://trello.com/)